# Right hand margin not working

Tags: html, css, margin

I am trying to find the best method for creating a section in the middle of a webpage similar to a piece of paper. For example, I have a grey background and then I want to put some content ontop of white.

My CSS looks like this:

```
body
{
    background:grey;
}

.page
{
    display: table;
    background:white;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0px 50px;
}
```

My php file looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
        hello this is the content
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

When I render the page in firefox, the right hand margin goes all the way to the end of the screen instead of being padded like it is on the left hand side...

Comment: Get rid of the display and width rules, set the margin to `margin:0 auto`, and then set a width on the div to something less than 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `div` with class name `page` as a wrapper?

then add an element `div` with attribute class name as `content` just like this

```css
body
{
    background:grey;
}

.page
{
    display: table;
    background:white;
    width:100%;
}
.content{
    background:red;
    margin: 0px 50px;
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<div class="page">
            <div class="content">hello this is the content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your width on the div is 100%. The margin on the left is 50px. So you're seeing the div being pushed 50px from the left edge of the body. You're NOT seeing the right margin because your width is equal to the width of the body, so technically the right edge is PAST the viewport.

Easy fix -- remove the width declaration and change the display to block.

```
.page {
    display: block;
    background:white;
    margin: 0px 50px;
}
```

A div is a block-level element by default, so it will naturally fill its container (the body, in this case). No need to specify width 100%. And really no need to declare its display, but I did here to emphasize the change from table to block.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I tried this and the white section is no longer centred in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have declared `.page` as `display:table` as the content within it (in your example) is not wrapped in anything with `display:table-cell`. However, assuming you *do* want it to remain as `display:table` then you'll need to remove the `margin` and use `padding` on its parent element (in this case the `body`).

```css
body {
    background:grey;
    padding:0 50px; /* <-- added padding */
}
.page {
    display: table;
    background:white;
    width:100%;
    /* removed margin */
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
        hello this is the content
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```